# Update product variation via the Woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to update product variation via the Woocommerce REST API.
I can create update endpoint with this kind of structure:
/products//variations/
I don't want to use parent_id. Is there any method to update product only with variation_id? (Variation_id is key like other product_ids, isn't it?)

Comment: Sorry, the endpoint structure format with partent id:
/products/<parent_id>/variations/<variation_id>

Answer (score -1):

Variation_id id is not key like other product_ids.

But you have to update the product details by SKU.

Go through with link: https://woocommerce-manager.com/useful-articles/woocommerce-product-management/woocommerce-import-variable-products-tutorial/

I hope that you can get some solution for your work.